# intellij code formatting: less

Tags: intellij-idea, less

How can I set the indentation to be tabs in less files with intellij ? I tried setting the 'use tab character' in 'editor>code style>less', but as the preview shows, most of the indents are not converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling **Use tab character** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | Less** is a right way to go. But you need to make sure that the specified **Indent** width is divisible by **Tab size** (i.e. if a **Tab size** is `4`, **Indent** and **Continuation Indent** values sh. be `4`, `8`, etc.) to get all indents converted